React Native Dynamic Navigation
Before upgrading RN 0.76.2 version i used Dynamic Navigation.I have add function, When I press the button, I transfer a name to the state in the context. I render a specific component on my Router page as well as the names in the state and direct it to that page. I also see the names of the open pages in the navbar.
After the update, that page is rendered, but when it will redirect to that page, it will first be instantaneously rendered. The page opens and goes back to my home page. Does this have anything to do with the new version?
CustomersList.js
    setAddPages(prevPages => {
      if (!prevPages.includes(editPage)) {
        return [...prevPages, editPage];
      }
      return prevPages;
    });

    setPendingNavigation({ page: editPage, params: {
      editData: response.data.Response,
      callerID: data.callerID,
    } });

    useEffect(() => {
if (pendingNavigation) {
  const { page, params } = pendingNavigation;

  if (addPages.includes(page)) {
    navigation.navigate(page, params);
    setPendingNavigation(null); 
  }
}
}, [addPages, pendingNavigation]);

Router.js
   {addPages !== '' && (addPages.map((name,index) => (
    <Drawer.Screen
    key={index}
    name={name}
    component={CustomersAdd}
    // options={{headerShown: false}}
    />
  )))}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
